# XenServer 6.2 DHCP Setup

Tags: xenserver, dhcp-server

I have a XenServer 6.2 running on a dedicated OVH Server.

For this dedicated server I have 2 additional IP blocks.

Whenever I setup a new VM (mostly CentOS 6.6) i have to skip the network configuration part and do it manually after.

Is there any way to configure a DHCP in the XenServer which will based on the MAC address of the VM assign the proper IP/Gateway/Nameserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just install ISC-DHCPD and configure DHCP reservations for your Xen DomUs.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done in the past.

Comment: I'm having difficulty with the same problem, but one step further. I went ahead and am not getting the `dhcpd` service to start successfully. I came across a similar question at the *linuxquestions* forums but without any details regarding the configuration. I posted my question on **serverfault** with all the information on I have available [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/792828/dhcp-server-not-starting-on-centos-5-xenserver-6-5). If there is a way to configure the `dhcpd` service, then it would be great to hear about it at that post.