# dhcp server not starting on CentOS 5 (XenServer 6.5)

Tags: centos5, xenserver, dhcp-server, static-ip, dhcpd

I have a host with XenServer 6.5 (based on CentOS 5) that is currently set up using a static IP by following the procedure [here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116372). I have been provided with an IP address, netmask and gateway - I entered these in the fields shown in figure 6 in the above link.

**Overview of setup:**

XenServer is installed on the host. There are 4 virtual machines that reside on the host as above. I have been assigned one static IP address. I assigned it to the host. Now, I need to set up a DHCP server on the host that I can use to provide IP addresses to all 4 virtual machines (clients). I was given the following static IP information:

```
Static IP: 156.74.180.143
Netmask: 255.255.255.224
DNS: 156.74.20.10, 156.189.111.61
Gateway: 156.74.180.225
Internal IPs*: 10.0.0.254, 127.0.0.1
```

*Internal IPs found using `ifconfig | perl -nle'/dr:(\S+)/ && print $1'`.

**DHCP Server - main problem**

The host appears to be successfully connecting to the internet. I can ping the gateway and google as shown below:

```
[ABCD@localhost ~]# ping -c 4 -n 10.0.0.254
PING 10.0.0.254 (10.0.0.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.254: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.254: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms

--- 10.0.0.254 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2997ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.033/0.047/0.061/0.014 ms

[ABCD@localhost ~]# ping -c 4 -n 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=2.87 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=2.71 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=2.81 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=2.69 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.699/2.777/2.879/0.082 ms
```

**dhcpd.conf file settings**

XenServer 6.5 is based on CentOS 5 so I followed a tecadmin article to install `dhcp`. Then I would configure my `dhcpd.conf` file.

First, I backed up the default `dhcpd.conf` file using:

```
$ yum -y install dhcp
$ cp --backup /etc/dhcpd.conf /etc/dhcpd.conf.back      #backup file
$ cp -f /usr/share/doc/dhcp-3.0.5/dhcpd.conf.sample /etc/dhcpd.conf
```

In the 3rd line above, this will use the sample `dhcpd.conf` file as template; in next step (below), I will make changes to template.

Okay, so then I started to customize my `dhcpd.conf` file and this is where I am having trouble. Here is the `dhcpd.config` file I am working with, based on [this](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_5&p=dhcp):

```
# line 4: specify your network and subnetmask
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
# line 7 : specify default gateway
option routers 156.74.180.143;

# line 8: specify subnetmask
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;

# line 12: specify IP address of DNS
option domain-name-servers 156.74.20.10, 156.189.111.61;

# line 14: comment out
option time-offset-18000;

# line 21: specify the range of IP addresses for clients
range 10.0.0.200 10.0.0.254;

# line 22: default terms of lease
default-lease-time 21600;

# line 23: maximun terms of lease
max-lease-time 43200;
```

After setting up this configuration, I started the `dhcp` service using:

```
$ service dhcpd stop
$ service dhcpd start
```

This gives me:

```
Starting dhcpd:                                            [FAILED]
```

Based on this, I would believe that my problem is isolated to my dhcpd configuration and *should* not be related to the XenServer host itself. Actually, it appears that the dhcp server is not able to start.

**Questions**

1. `option routers` - this is the gateway to be used by clients but, should this be the static IP address that I was given?
2. `range` - How do I pick the range of IP addresses? Should these be internal IP addresses eg. such as 10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.54?
3. I have not entered the static ip address of the host, netmask or gateway that I was given with the static IP. Are these needed in the `dhcpd.conf` file?
4. `netmask` - I used a subnet of 255.255.255.0. I was given 255.255.255.224 - do I need to use this or is 255.255.255.0 correct?
5. Is there something else I need to specify in order to successfully turn on the `dhcpd` service?

**EDIT: Additional Information**

I posted this question here as per [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/what-questions-belong-on-super-user-vs-server-fault), but if it would be best to ask this elsewhere, feel free to let me know. Thanks.

Comment: XenServer is stripped down a lot. No security patch got pushed there for other thing than xen service. You cant have a 5th VM to provide such functionality? (like pfsense or such)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I can't add more VMs to the host and we can't add network storage either. For the host, it seems that I have installed the package correctly and all the required files are present...it is just not letting me start the service and I think it is being caused by an incorrect `dhcpd.conf` file. However, do you mean that it is not possible to set up a dhcp server on a XenServer host? Is there a reason why it is not possible to do this?

Comment: Another question that I am finding difficult to understand: Is there another file that I need to change, besides `dhcpd.conf` or is a system restart required in order to get the DHCP server started correctly?

Comment: I cant tell sorry, Iam not a linux guru. I know xen, but only it standard option.

Comment: You should look at your dhcpd logs to determine what the problem is.

Comment: Thank Iain. I have tried these `journalctl | grep -Ei 'dhcp'`, `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -Ei 'dhcp'` and `cat /var/log/dhcpd.log` as per [here](http://superuser.com/questions/944687/how-to-see-what-dhcp-client-does). The first one returns `-bash: journalctl: command not found` and the other 2 both return `No such file or directory`. I couldn't find info on where CentOS logs this. Do you know where the `dhcp` logs can be retrieved from?